# sending array to codeigniter (php) controller using ajax and jquery and load page on existing loaded page (in any div)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
function showmypage(calculated){

    var sorteddata = JSON.stringify(calculated);
    myurl = URL + 'personalloan/getPLOffersbyfilter/eligibility';
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {data:sorteddata},
        dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(msg){
    $(".divoffersfilter").load(myurl);//here is error
    console.log(msg);
    });

}
```

I want to send array (calculated is array name) to the controller and this and load a dynamic PHP page using content in that array. But, here it treats ".load()" function separately. the ajax is processing the request and giving back the response but the **response is not loaded on view file**.

Comment: Please add the code for the URL being used to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are making two ajax requests to the same URL.

The first one is with the code

```
var request = $.ajax({
     url: myurl,
     ...
```

The second ajax call is in your `.done` block.

```
$(".divoffersfilter").load(myurl);
```

The `.load()` function is shorthand that essentially amounts to this.

```
$.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
                $(".divoffersfilter").html = data;
            }
        });
```

Without seeing the code that executes at the URL it is not possible to provide advice on which ajax approach to use. But you probably should not use both.

Comment: `function showmypage(calculated){<br/>
  var sorteddata = JSON.stringify(calculated);
   myurl = URL + 'personalloan/getPLOffersbyfilter/eligibility';
   var request = $.ajax({
         url: myurl,
         method: 'POST',
          data: {data:sorteddata},
           dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(msg){
              $(".divoffersfilter").html(msg);
        });
  }`